# What is the first Kanji in this image?

Tags: kanji, names, writing-identification

[image]

> ~口先生

Nothing comes to mind when I look at the first Kanji. I searched for Surnames with 口 in them but nothing seems to match.
[Here](http://kakijun.com/kanji/name/53e3.html) are all the surnames matching ~口

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks pretty clearly like it's [森口（もりぐち）](http://kakijun.com/c/68ee53e3.html).

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out the two 木's at the bottom. Thank you!